# do not see the icon web fonts on mobile devices with chrome

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I'm making a website with web icon fonts, it is a test site and have local mode. When this work always Fontastic use typography link remotely.

I am having a serious problem, I had never experienced before. My web icon fonts the chrome of the phone may not see. From the native mobile browser if they are, but when I use no chrome.

[image: Chrome vs native browser]

I've always used Fontastic and I have had no problems, I have another web currently has Fontastic and there all right.

Eye: This site previously had font-awesome, I've replaced by Fontastic. Suddenly a piece of code may be causing this?

I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: Did you checked whether the paths of all font files are correct?

Comment: Yes, the routes are correct.

Comment: Are you using the latest chrome?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of chrome.